# Returning empty list and CSV file Selenium Python

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]I am automating this link:

https://global.remax.com/officeagentsearch.aspx#!mode=list&type=2&regionId=1000&regionRowId=&provinceId=&cityId=&localzoneId=&name=&location=&spokenLanguageCode=&page=1&countryCode=US&countryEnuName=USA&countryName=USA&selmode=residential&officeId=&TargetLng=&TargetLat=

I am using a zip function to zip all the list into one. I use pandas to store data into CSV file but I am getting an empty list and CSV file. 
I don't see any error in the code, maybe I am missing something. 
Your help is appreciated.
Below is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

option = Options()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option, executable_path='your path\\chromedriver.exe')

driver.implicitly_wait(3)

url = "https://global.remax.com/officeagentsearch.aspx#!mode=list&type=2&regionId=1000&regionRowId=&provinceId=&cityId=&localzoneId=&name=&location=&spokenLanguageCode=&page=1&countryCode=US&countryEnuName=USA&countryName=USA&selmode=residential&officeId=&TargetLng=&TargetLat="

driver.get(url)

na = "N/A"

agent_name = []
remax_level = []
agent_phone_1 = []
agent_phone_2 = []
mobile = []
street_address = []
address_locality = []
address_region = []
address_country = []
email = []
website = []

for i in range(1, 6):
    agent_details = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'''//*[@id="list-container"]/div[1]/div/div[{i}]/div/div[1]/a''')
    agent_details.click()

    try:
        # scraping agent's name 
        name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="MainContent"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2/a''')
        agent_name.append(name.text)
    except:
        agent_name.append(na)

    try:
        # scraping remax level 
        level = driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="MainContent"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/h3/span/a/span''')
        remax_level.append(level.text)
    except:
        remax_level.append(na)

    try:
        # clicking on phone no 1
        phone_1 = driver.find_element_by_id("AgentDirectDialSpan")
        phone_1.click()
    except:
        pass

    try:
        # scraping phone no 1
        phone_1_copy = driver.find_element_by_class_name("phone-link")
        agent_phone_1.append(phone_1_copy.text)
    except:
        agent_phone_1.append(na)

    try:
        # clicking on phone no 2
        phone_2 = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl05_ShowOffice")
        phone_2.click()
    except:
        pass

    try:
        # scraping phone no 2
        phone_2_copy = driver.find_element_by_class_name("OfficePhoneSpan")
        agent_phone_2.append(phone_2_copy.text)
    except:
        agent_phone_2.append(na)

    try:   
        # clicking on mobile num
        mobile_num = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl05_ShowPhone")
        mobile_num.click()
    except:
        pass

    try:
        # scraping  mobile num
        mobile_n = driver.find_element_by_id("PhoneSpan")
        mobile.append(mobile_n.text)
    except:
        mobile.append(na)

    try:
        # scraping street address
        street_add = driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="ctl05_Address"]/span[1]''')
        street_address.append(street_add.text)
    except:
        street_address.append(na)

    try:
        # scraping address locality
        add_locality = driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="ctl05_Address"]/span[2]''')
        address_locality.append(add_locality.text)
    except:
        address_locality.append(na)

    try:
        # scraping address region
        add_region = driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="ctl05_Address"]/span[3]''')
        address_region.append(add_region.text)
    except:
        address_region.append(na)

    try:
        # scraping address country
        add_country = driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="ctl05_Address"]/span[4]''')
        address_country.append(add_country.text)
    except:
        address_country.append(na)

    try: 
        # scraping emails and websites
        emails_or_web = driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//span[contains(@class, 'value') and contains(@class, 'url-link') and position() = 1]''')

        if emails_or_web.text[6] or emails_or_web.text[7] == "http://" or "https://":
            website.append(emails_or_web.text)

        else:
            email.append(emails_or_web.text)
    except:
        website.append(na) and email.append(na)

    driver.back()
    continue

# zipping all the lists to one variable
all_info = list(zip(agent_name, remax_level, agent_phone_1, agent_phone_2, mobile, street_address, address_locality, address_country, email, website))
print(all_info)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_info, columns=["Agent Name", "Remax Level", "Agent Phone 1", "Agent Phone 2", "Agent Mobile", "Street Address", "Address Locality", "Address Country", "Email", "Website"])
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False, encoding = 'utf-8')
driver.close()
```

Comment: could you include one simple output of your desired target?

Comment: Hi, I added the picture to the question.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃ-αмєяιcαη Hi, I added the picture to the question

Comment: I've asked you a clear question to include a simple of your desired output. i see you have just included a picture and even you draw !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i see that you are just calling the main `url` and that's all ? How do you except to parse if you haven't even collected the `urls` in the main `url` and then call each `url` to parse it.

Even though you are using `selenium` for such task which is completely will slow down your job. therefor you have to read [selenium documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to understand how the way `selenium` is used.

You Haven't included any `sample` of your desired output. and there's things which i couldn't understood such as `level`. Anyway since you haven't be helpful for providing clear information.

below code should achieve your goal:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def First():
    r = requests.get("https://global.remax.com/handlers/officeagentsearch.ashx?mode=list&type=2&regionId=1000&regionRowId=&provinceId=&cityId=&localzoneId=&name=&location=&spokenLanguageCode=&page=1&countryCode=US&countryEnuName=USA&countryName=USA&selmode=residential&officeId=&TargetLng=&TargetLat=")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    data = []
    for href in soup.find_all("a", class_="agent-name"):
        href = href.get("href"), href.text
        data.append(href)
    return data


def Second():
    for url, name in First():
        print(f"Extracting {name}")
        print('*' * 40)
        with requests.Session() as req:
            r = req.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
            phone = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in soup.findAll(
                "span", {'id': ['AgentDirectDialSpan', 'OfficePhoneSpan', 'PhoneSpan']})]
            print(phone)
            addr = [item.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ") for item in soup.findAll(
                "span", id="ctl05_OfficeAddress")]
            print(addr)
            emailandurl = soup.find("a", {'class': 'url'})
            email = emailandurl.text
            url = emailandurl.get("href")
            if not "@" in email:
                email = "N/A"
            if "@" in url:
                url = "N/A"
            print(f"Email : {email}, Url: {url}")

        print('*' * 40)


Second()
```

Output:

```
Extracting Jim & Lisa - THE COOPERS
****************************************
['+1 816-260-1459', '+1 816-781-9080', '+1 816-260-8592']
['2 Victory Dr Liberty, Missouri, United States 64068']
Email : N/A, Url: http://soldbythecoopers.com
****************************************
Extracting Jim & Jimmie Rucker - The Rucker Group
****************************************
['+1 816-739-5289', '+1 816-781-9080', '+1 816-739-5289']
['2 Victory Dr Liberty, Missouri, United States 64068']
Email : N/A, Url: http://jimmierucker.remax-midstates.com
****************************************
Extracting The Steve & Shauna Faught Team !
****************************************
['+1 8053829441', '+1 (805) 208-1826']
['1151 S Victoria Ave Oxnard, California, United States 93035']
Email : shaunafaught@remax.net, Url: N/A
****************************************
Extracting Vickie Soupos & Georgia Colovos
****************************************
['+1 847.352.5200', '+1 847-352-5200', '+1 630.965.6000']
['1080 Nerge Rd. Suite 204 Elk Grove Village, Illinois, United States 60007']
Email : N/A, Url: http://vickiecsoupos.engagereagent.com
****************************************
Extracting Steven Roque & Jan Meyer
****************************************
['+1 (858) 451-6541', '+1 8583915800', '+1 (858) 451-6541']
['16840 Bernardo Center Dr. San Diego, California, United States 92128']
Email : stevenproque@remax.net, Url: N/A
****************************************
Extracting Gabrielle (clark) Lawson
****************************************
['+1 (937) 778-3961', '+1 9377783961', '+1 (937) 418-1718']
['1200 Park Ave Piqua, Ohio, United States 45356']
Email : brandi.clark@remax.net, Url: N/A
****************************************
Extracting The Beauchamp Team (Pam & Heather)
****************************************
['+1 3867588900', '+1 (386) 303-2505']
['4255 SW Cambridge Glen Lake City, Florida, United States 32024-3431']
Email : pamelabeauchamp@remax.net, Url: N/A
****************************************
Extracting Amanda (Ritter) Lease
****************************************
['+1 6128125732', '+1 (952) 475-8000', '+1 6128125732']
['125 Lake St West Wayzata, Minnesota, United States 55391']
Email : N/A, Url: http://amandalease.results.net
****************************************
Extracting The Manring Brothers @ REMAX
****************************************
['+1 (239) 289-6913', '+1 2397932777', '+1 (239) 289-6915']
['877 91st Ave N Suite 2 Naples, Florida, United States 34108']
Email : tylermanring@remax.net, Url: N/A
****************************************
Extracting Logan M. Aal
****************************************
['+1 (303) 456-2153', '+1 3034205352', '+1 (303) 501-0294']
['5440 Ward Rd Ste 110 Arvada, Colorado, United States 80002']
Email : loganaal@remax.net, Url: N/A
****************************************
Extracting Abe Aalami
****************************************
['+1 (425) 743-1639', '+1 2063225700', '+1 (206) 948-6283']
['2312 Eastlake Ave E Seattle, Washington, United States 98102']
Email : abe.aalami@remax.net, Url: N/A
****************************************
Extracting Lacey Aalderks
****************************************
['+1 3202311221', '+1 (320) 266-1631']
['770 N Business Hwy 71 Willmar, Minnesota, United States 56201']
Email : N/A, Url: http://www.laceyaalderks.com
****************************************
Extracting Andrea Aana
****************************************
['+1 (808) 935-8300', '+1 8089359800', '+1 (808) 937-6396']
['88 Kanoelehua Ave #A-105 Hilo, Hawaii, United States 96720']
Email : andreaaana@remax.net, Url: N/A
****************************************
Extracting Adam Aaron
****************************************
['+1 3039854555', '+1 (225) 571-5111']
['143 Union Blvd Ste 120 Lakewood, Colorado, United States 80228-1827']
Email : Adam.Aaron@remax.net, Url: N/A
****************************************
Extracting Bryan Aaron
****************************************
['+1 2812456463', '+1 (832) 526-1973']
['203 S Friendswood Dr Ste 200 Friendswood, Texas, United States 77546-3901']
Email : Bryan.Aaron@remax.net, Url: N/A
****************************************
Extracting Lindsey Aaron
****************************************
['+1 (877) 407-2676']
['7101 Vista Drive West Des Moines, Iowa, United States 50266']
Email : N/A, Url: http://lindseyaaronrealestate.com
****************************************
Extracting Mary Aaron
****************************************
['+1 (214) 802-3954', '+1 9724628181']
['500 S Denton Tap Ste 110 Coppell, Texas, United States 75019']
Email : betha@remax.net, Url: N/A
****************************************
Extracting Noelle Aasen
****************************************
['+1 (317) 863-4088', '+1 3178497653', '+1 (317) 627-2120']
['5645 Castle Creek Parkway North Dr. Indianapolis, Indiana, United States 46250']
Email : N/A, Url: http://151354589.homesconnect.com
****************************************
Extracting Kristy Aasheim
****************************************
['+1 4068962200']
['517 S 24th St W Ste A Billings, Montana, United States 59102']
Email : kristyaasheim@remax.net, Url: N/A
****************************************
Extracting Kristy L. Aasheim
****************************************
['+1 (406) 480-9383', '+1 7015808116']
['115 2nd Ave W Williston, North Dakota, United States 58801-5918']
Email : kaasheim@remax.net, Url: N/A
****************************************
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly sure what your issue is since I'm not manually testing your code, but assuming you have the proper xpaths and id's for your elements, I would guess that you're trying to get a .text attribute from a list object (a list of web elements). So you need to add the `.text` attribute to each individual element. For example, if the xpath in

`name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="MainContent"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2/a''')
        agent_name.append(name.text)`

finds all the name elements on the page for 'Joe Smith, Bob Jones, etc...', you want to add loop that allows you to add the `.text` attribute to each element. For example:

`names = driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="MainContent"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2/a''')
for name in names:
    agent_name.append(name.text)`

This should at least populate your lists. If this doesn't work I would double check that the things you're trying to scrape are indeed text attributes in the html (ie. not images), and ensure your element identifiers are correct and that you're following the recommendations/syntax in the docs for python selenium.

Comment: is your chrome instance running successfully? If not, you need to update the path to your chromedriver.exe file